# Inno Setup - Changing only .bin files name

Tags: inno-setup

It is possible to change name only of .bin files and left setup as a setup.exe?

I mean:
setup.exe
data1.bin
data2.bin
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

Both `.exe` and `.bin` output file names are based on [`OutputBaseFilename`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputbasefilename).

Comment: OK. Thanks for answer anyway :)